# Make a instance of the Object returned by the THEE.js OBJMTLLoader

Tags: three.js

I'm deply sory about ask this question again here. I know that the members os Stack Overflow are not for my exclusive
use but a realy need to find a solution to this problem.

Let me explain better because last time I was not that clear about what I wanted.

Iam using the THREE.JS to develop a RPG like game. What I have in mind is a game just like IronBane MMO but without
the web server function for now (just use for the single player).

I'm relative new to THREE.js and, in some point, I start to work in a library to handle the object loadings im
my level. Because I use the 3DStudio Max to make de models, I decide to use the OBJMTLLoader library provided.

I've nailed the function to load de static objects and its something like this.

```
function loadObject(obj,mtl,pos){   // Adiciona objeto sem vinculá-lo a uma variável
    var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
        loader.load( obj, mtl, function ( object ) {
            object.position.set(pos[0],pos[1],pos[2]);
            scene.add( object );
    });
}
```

The problem comes when I need to intance this object. I tried many things for example:

```
function addObject(obj,mtl){    // Declara e adiciona um objeto no mapa

var conteudo;

var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
loader.load( obj,mtl, function( object ){
    conteudo = object;
});

setTimeout(function(){
    scene.add( conteudo );
},1000);
```

The conteudo variable came undefined of course. I understand then that I need to wait the object to load first. It
takes about 2 render cicles. For this I use then the setTimeout function. With the scene.add( conteudo ) the object
was sucessfuly added to the scene. I try then to use a

```
return conteudo;
```

and, when I call...

```
var objeto = new addObject('object path','material path')
```

I get a instance of addObject and not Object3D as I expected. I try also to declare a array outside de function and 
push it from inside the addObject like this:

```
function addObject(obj,mtl,objectArray)

var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
loader.load( obj,mtl, function( object ){
    conteudo = object;
});

setTimeout(function(){
    scene.add( conteudo );
    objectArray.push( conteudo );
},1000);
```

In this second one when I console.log the array I get:

```
Array[1]
    0 : THREE.Object3D
    length : 1
```

but when I try to use Array[0] or console.log(Array.length) I get undefined and 0 respectivly.

I would realy appreciate if someone could help-me solve this one. That would be awesome. Thanks you!

Comment: Don't you mean `var objeto = addObject()` not `var objeto = new addObject()`?

Answer (score 0):

consider waiting with adding the objects.

```
function init(next){

    var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
        loader.load( obj, mtl, function ( object ) {
            object.position.set(pos[0],pos[1],pos[2]);
            conteudo = object;
            next();
    });

}

function next(){
    scene.add( conteudo );
    objectArray.push( conteudo );
    console.log(objectArray)

    ... work from here, here you are sure that the model is loaded ... 

}

init(next);
```

This waits until the object is loaded and then it will execute next.

Comment: Thanks Gero3 this already helps a lot. A problem occurs however when i try to return de Object3D.

Comment: The Array inside the addObject function returns a Object3D (as expected) but outside this function it returns addObject itself